# What scientific field studies diagnostics?

Tags: single-word-requests, science

What is the name of the field of scientific study which covers "the process of diagnosing the cause of problems", independent of any specific knowledge domain? i.e. it would cover the common elements (like diagnostic tests) that occur whether you are seeking to diagnose a disease or debug a computer program.

Comment: Not a single word, but the activity is usually referred to as *causal analysis*

Answer (score 1):

This is the field of ***[abductive reasoning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abductive_reasoning)***

> Abductive reasoning (also called abduction, abductive inference, or
>   retroduction) is a form of logical inference which starts with an
>   observation then seeks to find the simplest and most likely
>   explanation.

(Wikipedia)

In [***medicine***](http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/thinking/reasoning.html):-

> A medical diagnosis is an application of abductive reasoning: given
>   this set of symptoms, what is the diagnosis that would best explain
>   most of them?

(Butte College)

In [program debugging](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=O-ZHAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=Program%20debugging%20is%20an%20abductive%20task%20in%20which%20a%20problem%20solver%20attempts%20to%20find%20an&source=bl&ots=98nKWevmAd&sig=GmmvMq5YKLxadjZFik5qvXC4PkQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit542Io7rTAhWRLVAKHbH3CSUQ6AEICjAA#v=onepage&q=Program%20debugging%20is%20an%20abductive%20task%20in%20which%20a%20problem%20solver%20attempts%20to%20find%20an&f=false):-

> Program debugging is an abductive task in which a problem solver
>   attempts to find an explanation (eg., a line of code) for certain
>   symptoms (e.g., an error message).

(Complex Problem Solving: The European Perspective)

Comment: Yes it was the best I could find when I researched it.

Answer (score 0):

**Maintenance engineering**

> The major maintenance engineering contributions
>   to a materiel program are to insure
>   that the materiel is designed for ease and economy
>   of support, **to define and develop an adequate
>   and economic maintenance support subsystem
>   that will be available when the materiel
>   is deployed**, and to monitor and improve the
>   subsystem until the materiel is removed from
>   the inventory. Design for ease and economy of
>   support is obtained by determining optimum
>   levels of materiel reliability, maintainability,
>   human factors, safety, and transportability design
>   features, and transmitting these features
>   as requirements to design engineers.

Emphasis mine.

http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a021390.pdf

In addition to diagnostic systems, maintenance engineering deals with issues of reliability, self sufficiency vs depot repair, and the overall state of readiness of the system.

Comment: That would appear to be a specific to a knowledge domain, in this case engineering.  I was hoping for diagnostics in the abstract sense.